# Using nth Term Test to find if $\cos(\frac{1}{n})$ is divergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

So in this problem I'm required to use the nth term test for:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\cos(\frac{1}{n})$$

I made it into:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}cos(\frac{1}{n})$$

I think it's going to diverge because cosine oscillates, but I don't know how to prove it with the nth term limit that I have above. Would I just divide by $\frac{cos\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n}}$? I'm lost.

Comment: What’s cosine of 0?

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty}1/n=0$, so what is $\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos(1/n)$?

Comment: If the $\cos$ was replaced by a $\sin$, that'd be a whole other story.

Comment: @RushabhMehta Would it?  $\sin(1/n)\approx 1/n$...

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I meant as in a more interesting problem. I'm aware both diverge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \cos (\frac{1}{n}) = \cos (0) = 1 \neq 0$$
then the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\cos(\frac{1}{n})$$
will diverge.

Answer (score 1):

Since $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\cos(\frac{1}{n})\ne 0 $$ the series does not converge.

To show that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\cos(\frac{1}{n})\ne 0 $$ it suffices to show that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\cos(\frac{1}{n})=\cos (0)=1 $$